# SQL Help (OrgID & ToolID default issues)

Tags: sql

Stored procedure sp_ORG_ORGANIZATIONS_CreateDefaultTools copies the defaults from OrgId = 0 to a newly specified OrgId.  But when I copy no matter what the default status for the new ToolID and OrgID always have a status of 1

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ORG_TOOLS](
[OrgId] [int] NOT NULL,
[ToolId] [int] NOT NULL,
[Status] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_ORG_TOOLS_Status]  DEFAULT ((1))
)
```

---

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE dbo.sp_ORG_ORGANIZATIONS_CreateDefaultTools
@OrgId INT
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

INSERT INTO ORG_TOOLS( OrgId, ToolId)
(SELECT @OrgId, ToolId 
FROM ORG_TOOLS 
WHERE OrgId = 0)

GO
```

Comment: Because you do not set a value for the STATUS the DEFAULT is applied each time you run your stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to set the status in the `insert`?  Just a guess:

```
INSERT INTO ORG_TOOLS( OrgId, ToolId, Status)
    SELECT @OrgId, ToolId, Status
    FROM ORG_TOOLS 
    WHERE OrgId = 0;
```